# Fox Pro 8 - Export to Spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet, foxpro

I don't have much programming knowledge, but I have a data set on a CD in the FoxPro format and I need to know if it can be exported to something like Google Docs in the form of a spreadsheet.

Comment: Try opening the file in Microsoft Excel first (if you have that).  I think you can go from Excel to Google Docs directly...

Answer (score 2):

If you have any version of FoxPro or Visual FoxPro, you can use the COPY TO command or the Export Wizard to turn each table into an Excel spreadsheet (with some limitations). Excel can open some older format DBFs, so depending how old your data is, you may be able to just open it from Excel specifying "dBase files."

FoxPro tables can also be exported in CSV format, which a spreadsheet should be able to read. Again, you'd need FoxPro for that.

If you have the VFP ODBC driver, you can use to open the data and export it.

Comment: Excel versions before 2007 can open DBF files - after that the only thing in the Office Suite that can is MS Access.